# How to create Regex to validate logical AND OR operators in string

Tags: c#, regex, string, validation

I want to create a Regex expression to validate logical AND OR string combonation and its corresponding opening and closing () brackets. i am using C#

```
string validator = @"^(?=^[^()]*(?>[^()]+|\((?<DEPTH>)|\)(?<-DEPTH>))*(?(DEPTH)(?!))[^()]*$)[(]*[0-9a-zA-Z]+[)]*(\s+(AND|OR)\s+[(]*[0-9a-zA-Z]+[)]*)*$";
```

when i tried with below cases its working
(xyz AND abcd)
((abc AND jkr) AND (3 OR 4))

but when i tried with below cases its not working
(xyz AND abcd efg)
((abc AND jkr) AND (3 OR 4 abcd))

Comment: Why?  What are you ultimately trying to do?

Comment: I tried to validate long string query

Comment: What do you mean when you said it is not working. Is it considering the expression as valid or not ?

Comment: Recursion (?R) is not supported in .NET for regex so you can not  soley depend on regex to solve this problem.